# Finding possible forms of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $c > 0$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider the function $f(z) = e^{c(z-g(z))}$, where $g$ is analytic on the half plane $P_a = \{z:\Re(z) > a\}$. Suppose $f$ is bounded on $P_a$, say by some constant $M$.

My question is, what forms could $g$ possibly take?

I'm aware that $g$ can be $z+z_0$ where $z_0$ is some appropriate complex number, but apart from that I don't have an intuition of how to proceed. Any hints or concrete answers are welcome! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may as well consider $h(z) = z - g(z)$.  Then what you need is just that $h$ is analytic on $P_a$ and $\text{Re}(h(z))$ is bounded above on $P_a$. There are 
too many such $h$ to characterize them.  For example, you could take $h(z) = H((z-a+1)/(z-a-1))$ where $H$ is analytic on the closed unit disk.